# Make newsletter popup dissapear to subscribed customers

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, popup

I have a popup newsletter subscription form in the home page.

The thing I want is to dissapear it to the login customers that have allready subscribe

The popup code is:

```
<?php /* Newsletter */ ?>

<?php $config2 = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_home_page'); 
       $delimeterPosition = strrpos($config2, '|');
       if ($delimeterPosition) {
          $config2 = substr($config2, 0, $delimeterPosition);
       }
?>
<?php $get_current_layout = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($config2, 'identifier')->getRootTemplate(); ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function(){
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
    var overlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay"></div>');
      overlay.show();
      overlay.appendTo(document.body);
      jQuery('.popup1').show();

      jQuery('.x').click(function(){
         if (document.getElementById('notshowpopup').checked) {
            var oneDays = 1000*60*60*24*1;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + oneDays);
            document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        }
      jQuery('.popup1').hide();
      overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
      return false;

  });
}
});
</script>

<div class="popup1">

  <div class="newsletter-sign-box">

<div class="newsletter">
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/f-box-close-icon.png') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('close') ?>" class="x" id="x" />
<div id="formSuccess1" style="display:none;"><?php echo $this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'); ?></div>

    <form method="post" id="popup-newsletter" name="popup-newsletter" class="email-form">
        <h3><?php echo $this->__('ΕΓΓΡΑΦΗ ΣΤΟ NEWSLETTER') ?></h3>
        <h4><?php echo $this->__('Γραφτείτε στο Newsletter μας για να μαθαίνετε πρώτοι για τις super προσφορές μας καθώς και για τα νέα μας προϊόντα.') ?></h4>
     <div class="newsletter-form">
        <div class="input-box">
           <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter2" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" placeholder="Διεύθυνση email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />        
           <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" class="button subscribe" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Εγγραφή') ?></span></button>
           <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/mgkloading1.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading') ?>" id="loader1" style="display:none;margin-left:120px;margin-top:10px;">
        </div> <!--input-box-->
     </div> <!--newsletter-form-->
        <label class="subscribe-bottom"><input type="checkbox" name="notshowpopup" id="notshowpopup"><?php echo $this->__('Να μην ξαναεμφανιστεί') ?></label>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var formId1 = 'popup-newsletter';
    var myForm1 = new VarienForm(formId1, true);
    var postUrl1 = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('_secure' => true)) ?>";
    function doAjax1() {
        if (myForm1.validator.validate()) {
    if (document.getElementById('notshowpopup').checked) {
            var oneDays = 1000*60*60*24*1;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + oneDays);
            document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
        }
            var request = new Ajax.Request(      
            postUrl1,
            {
                method: 'post',      
                onLoading: function() {   
                  document.getElementById('loader1').style.display='inline';   
                },
                onComplete: function(transport){ // Defining Complete Callback Function                     
                     $(formId1).hide();
                     $('formSuccess1').show();       

                },
                parameters: $(formId1).serialize(true)    // Seriallizing the form input values
            }
            );
            return false;

        }

    }

  new Event.observe(formId1, 'submit', function(e){
    e.stop();
    doAjax1();
  });

//]]>
</script>

</div> <!--newsletter-->

  </div> <!--newsletter-sign-box-->
</div> <!--popup1-->
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether customer is subscribed using below code and disable it

```
$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->load(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId());
if ($subscriber->getId()) {
    // put your logic here...
}
```